# How can I write a set of qunit tests that are executed in sequence?

Tags: javascript, qunit

I am using qunit to invoke a set of tests. These tests depend on an external fixture server, that preserves state as the tests are executed.

It appears that QUnit.test() declarations are not executed in order. Instead, they are spawned all at the same time. I also tried to do a single QUnit.test(), with the callback containing all operations, but as my operations are asynchronous I can't execute them in sequence unless I nest very deep promise.then() hierarchies.

Is there a way of suspending execution (e.g. like having a `assert.async().wait()`) so that I can be sure that operations are executed one after another, or any other way of having qunit tests performed sequentially somehow?

Comment: If they have to be executed in order, they aren't a unit test. That said, http://www.educatedguesswork.org/2011/06/curse_you_qunit_1.html

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: pragmatism beats purity. I can't stop and start my server from javascript for every new test.

Comment: Still not a unit test. Should be mocking the server for that. I'd just do one integration test per interaction scenario. Liable to be fragile, so how likely  change is, is a factor for pragmatism.